# How to fix the endless work of my parser on PHP and CURL?

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I need to make a parser that will read the specified number of links for example 80. I can’t figure out how to save or read all the links displayed on the screen. Now the parser is working endlessly.

```php
<?php
$page = 1;
$var = array();
$total = fPars('https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a892f816404e77/noutbuki/?p=1&order=1&groupBy=none&stock=2', $page, $var);

function fPars($parsLink, $page, &$var){
    $arr = parse_url($parsLink);
    parse_str($arr['query'],$query);
    $query['p'] = $page;
    $query = http_build_query($query);
    $url = $arr['scheme'].'://'.$arr['host'].$arr['path'].'?'.$query;

    $html = curl_get($url);
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $links = $dom->find('.product-info__title-link');
    $page = $page +1;
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        echo $link . '<br/>';
    }
    $var = array_merge($var,$links);
    echo count($var) . '<br/>';
    if (count($var) < 80) {
                fPars($url, $page, $var);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Then each page has less than 80 links. Add another condition to stop the recursion.

Comment: yes there are 18 links on each page, so it turns over endlessly, but I need to somehow do it to count the number of links found on all pages and when it reaches 80 it should stop

Comment: Add a parameter for the collected links (pass by reference). Or return the array of links and add the links from recursive calls to the local array.

Comment: Made through (Passing by Reference). Is it possible in a little more detail on the second method? Just if I get an array of links with **return**, my recursion is interrupted before the **if**.

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer with code... sec. edit: Oh, didn't realize you've changed your post. Yeah, looks ok with a reference variable.

Comment: If it’s not difficult for you, can you tell me how to do it in the second way?

Comment: With return the array of links and add the links from recursive calls to the local array. I can’t understand how to return the result, because if I return the function is interrupted. And how to write to an array . In my opinion this is something like
**$Arr = array_merge($Arr, $links)**